# Android Custom Shape Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

How can i make a custom shaped clickable view or button in Android?

When I click , I want to avoid touching on an empty area .

[image]

please help. Thank you.

Comment: Use relative layout and image button. It is possible.

Comment: check this link for custom shape click http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008959/android-image-with-clickable-areas

Comment: @Erhan, You can check my answer... It will work for u

Comment: [Custom Shape Button which ignores touches on transparent background (code).](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19583072/2678584)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Interesting question. I tried some solutions and this is what I found that has the same result of what you are trying to achieve. The solution below resolves 2 problems:

1. Custom shape as you presented it
2. The top right side of the button shouldn't be clickable

So this is the solution in 3 steps:

### Step 1

Create two shapes.

- First simple rectangle shape for the button: **shape_button_beer.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

      <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:endColor="#C5D9F4"
          android:startColor="#DCE5FD" />

      <corners
          android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
          android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="5dp" >
      </corners>

  </shape>
  ```
- Second shape is used as mask for the top right side of the button: **shape_button_beer_mask.xml**. It is simple circle with black solid color.

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="oval" >

      <solid android:color="#000000" />

  </shape>
  ```

### Step 2

In your main layout add the button by next approach:

- RelativeLayout is the container of this custom button
- First LinearLayout is the blue button with beer icon and text inside
- Second ImageView is the mask above the blue button. And here comes dirty trick:

  1. Margins are negative to set the mask in the right place
  2. We define id to be able override on click (see step 3)
  3. `android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"` - such that user will not feel that he pressed on something.

The XML:

```
    <!-- Custom Button -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/custom_buttom"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_button_beer" >

            <!-- Beer icon and all other stuff -->

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/beer_icon" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/do_nothing"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_button_beer_mask"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" >
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!-- End Custom Button -->
```

### Step 3

In your main activity you define on click events for both: button and the mask as follow:

```
LinearLayout customButton = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.custom_buttom);
customButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

// Mask on click will do nothing
ImageView doNothing = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.do_nothing);
doNothing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0)
    {
        // DO NOTHING
    }
});
```

That's it. I know that is not a perfect solution but in your described use case it could help.
I have tested it on my mobile and this is how it looks when you click on the blue area and nothing will happen on other areas:

- [image]

Hope it helped somehow :)

Comment: No problem. Hope that it will pass your tests :)

Comment: @sromku Thanks for your code. However, there is a problem. What if the black area in the image is not black but transparent so that whatever is the background, it will be visible through that transparent area. In my scenario there is an image instead of that black background. How will I do it?

Answer (score 15):

Use OnTouch instead of OnClick and check the alpha value of image you have used in the button.If its not equal to zero, do whatever you want.
Check the followig code,

```
final Bitmap bitmap;  //Declare bitmap     
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.TheImage);


public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();
        float iX=event.getX();
    float iY=event.getY();

        switch (eventPadTouch) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (iX>=0 & iY>=0 & iX<bitmap.getWidth() & iY<bitmap.getHeight()) { //Makes sure that X and Y are not less than 0, and no more than the height and width of the image.                
                    if (bitmap.getPixel((int) iX, (int) iY)!=0) {
                        // actual image area is clicked(alpha not equal to 0), do something 
                    }               
                }
                return true;                
        }           
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

u can try this one:

```
        <Button
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="ContactsDetails"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_marginLeft="50dp" android:background="@drawable/round"/>
```

and create round.xml file in drawable folder:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="0dp" android:useLevel = "false">
    <!-- you can use any color you want I used here gray color-->
     <solid android:color="#ABABAB"/> 
       <corners
       android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
       android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topRightRadius="70dp"/>
       </shape>
```

Comment: what would happen if the user presses the empty area ? will it catch the event or not? if it will , how can you overcome this problem?

Comment: it will not catch the empty area event

Comment: just tested it (using emulator since it's hard to touch exactly on the correct spot) , and you are incorrect - touching on an empty area will still trigger onClick (and onTouch, of course) .  question is, how to avoid it .

Comment: @G M Ramesh thank you. I tried to your code. But I can click on an empty area. I want to avoid touching on an empty area. How I can it?

Comment: @ErhanDemirci, i have edited the answer, please check once.... i added android:useLevel = "true"

Answer (score 3):

use layer-list, You can design any shape any gradient button tops 
here is example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners

                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                />            
            <!-- The border color -->
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
            <shape>            
            <gradient                
                android:startColor="#002a36"
                android:centerColor="#457c8e"
                android:endColor="#e6ffff"               
                android:angle="90" 
                  android:centerY="1"
                android:centerX="0.5"           
                />          

            <corners

                android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
                android:topRightRadius="0dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="2dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
                />            
            <padding
                android:left="10dp"
                android:top="10dp"
                android:right="10dp"
                android:bottom="10dp" 
                />                        
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

use -ve radius values to make button shape as u mentioned

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but I did not want to depend on code behind to examine the pixel value. I wanted a simple way (not class overloading) to constrain a touch event to only a sub portion of a drawable. Below I use a LinearLayout for the drawable and then inside that I put a transparent button (with text). I can adjust the margin of the button to position the clickable area.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/circle">
        <Button
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/btnTimer1"
            android:text="0:00"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best and easiest solution (as4me) I found [here - it is subclassed Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074303/how-to-create-custom-shape-button-with-selector-in-android/19583072#19583072) and thus it supports selector. So all you need to do is to draw/add corresponding pngs for every button state to use selector and declare onClick in xml or add OnClickListener in code and you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing all those changes, you should use frame layout at the portion that surrounds the button, and mask the top right portion with some thingy(circular, like a rounded button) and assign no click listener on that part. This in effect hides the lower frame(i.e. your original button) and masks it with the non active part.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answer by @Basim Sherif ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516572/1321026)) and it works great however only if the button size is the same as the original image. If the button was stretched up then the clickable region will be smaller and if the button was set to a smaller size the clickable region will be bigger than the actual button.

The solution is simple which is to scale the iX and iY values to match the original bitmap.

And here is my modified version of the code:

```
final Bitmap bitmap;  //Declare bitmap     
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.TheImage);

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();
    float iX=event.getX();
    float iY=event.getY();

    // Get the dimensions used in the view
    int realW = this.getWidth();
    int realH = this.getHeight();

    // Get the dimensions of the actual image
    int bitmapW = bitmap.getWidth();
    int bitmapH = bitmap.getHeight();

    // Scale the coordinates from the view to match the actual image
    float scaledX = iX * bitmapW / realW;
    float scaledY = iY * bitmapH / realH;

    switch (eventPadTouch) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (scaledX >= 0 & scaledY >= 0 & scaledX < bitmap.getWidth() & scaledY < bitmap.getHeight()) { //Makes sure that X and Y are not less than 0, and no more than the height and width of the image.                
                if (bitmap.getPixel((int) scaledX, (int) scaledY)!=0) {
                    // actual image area is clicked(alpha not equal to 0), do something 
                }
            }
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```