# Android non-rectangular buttons, how to handle this?

Tags: android, button

I've designed some buttons with photoshop but now it came in my mind the problem on how make them work.

Basically I've this image

[image: My buttons]

I've thought about two solutions: the first one is to place them in a RelativeLayout and place them with "lot" of padding/margin work, the second solution is to cut them vertically and attach them one by one, like this:

[image: My buttons2]

In the second solution I cannot probably use selector, not on all the button at least, not a big issue btw. With the first one I'm a bit worried about scaling on different screen sizes.

It will be a problem? Which solution would you suggest?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of buttons.. you can try with image views right...And yes i know its not the right answer.. Even i am waiting for some one to answer this question... @Enrichman

Comment: @amal ImageViews will work in the same manner

Comment: did you consider to write a custom View? You could make a custom View for an entire row of buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a must that your clickable area should be the same shape as your image shape..
[image]

Change the Image onclick...

If your options are open to use an image view instead of button, Then the whole image will be clickable.

I searched all over to find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13861416/2219600) similar to yours.. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this seems a nice solution. I will wait for other to see if something else will come out. :)

Comment: I think you won the quest, that's probably the best solution. :p
Btw I've endend changing the icons (I didn't like the result, lol). Thanks again