# On click event with a concave or convex view

Tags: android

i am creating and android turn based game with Android SDK.

My problem is i don't know how to detect an onclick event of a form like this with a selector, since selector only have oval, rectangle, ring and line form.

[image]

Any idea?

## Solution

According to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/14516572/2139691 the complete code of a custom view for a concave or convex forms would be this:

```
public class CustomView extends View {

private final Bitmap bitmap;

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
}

@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, this.getX(), getY(), null);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    float iX = event.getX();
    float iY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //Makes sure that X and Y are not less than 0, and no more than the height and width of the image.
        if (iX >= 0 & iY >= 0 & iX < bitmap.getWidth() & iY < bitmap.getHeight()) {
            if (bitmap.getPixel((int) iX, (int) iY) != 0) {
                Log.i("Custom view", "Touched!!!");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

}
```

### Hope it helps to others who looks for the tittle "concave or convex views"  instead of a "custom view".

Answer (score 2):

This post pretty much suggests a couple of solutions to your problem [Android Custom Shape Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button)