# Android custom shape button or imageview hit area

Tags: android, layout, shapes

Here is the scenario; I have 3 PNG photos i wanna use as background of buttons or ImageViews and they are overlapping in a relative layout. kinda like this:

[image: RelativeLayout]

so the red button will be the biggest and go under all of them, then i will add green button on top of red and then yellow button on top of green. so that's how it looks like. each button has a PNG background as i said at the beginning.

Problem is I cant make the only visible area of each Button/ImageView clickable! Android kinda considers each at rectangle button/ImageView.
Any solution for this?

Comment: You have to implement an OnTouchListener which checks whether or not the user touched unto the image itself or not.

Comment: i did; didnt work, still half of the green for example is considered as yellow.

Comment: You have to use the touch coordinates given to you by the MotionEvent to check if they are inside the image. It's not an easy calculation in that case.

Comment: i found this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button - but i dont know what to replace bitmap.getPixel with since i used ImageView or button. any suggestion?

Comment: You can always get another instance of the image you're using as a Bitmap, then use that to call "getPixel"

Comment: [Custom Shape Button which ignores touches on transparent background.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19583072/2678584)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`onTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) you should check whether the *event* (`MotionEvent`) is in the transparent area of the background or not.

Either you can make a separate `onTouchListener` for each view/button and return false if the event is in the transparent area (of the `View` argument) or you can make a single listener for all of the buttons, ignore the `View` argument and check all of your three views to determine in which one the event is.