# Fragment with ListView stays

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment

I have an Activity and 3 fragments. At the bottom of the main activity I have 3 buttons for switching the active fragment. Each fragment contains a ListView, do you think is a good way of development? I've developed the first Fragment downloading json from server, parsing and adding the element to the ListView, but when I press the button to switch to the Fragment2 the first one stays.

This is the main activity, the Fragment with the listView is using a custom adapter within some TextView and one ImageView. If I remove the listView, the fragments change without troubles.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class Home extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
         Fragment fr;
         int stringTitleID = R.string.title_fragment1;

         if(view == findViewById(R.id.imgBtn3))
         {
             fr = new FragmentThree();
             stringTitleID = R.string.title_fragment3;
         }
         else if(view == findViewById(R.id.imgBtn2))
         {
             fr = new FragmentTwo();
             stringTitleID = R.string.title_fragment2;
         }
         else
         {
             fr = new FragmentOne();
             stringTitleID = R.string.title_fragment1;
         }

         FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();

         // I change the title in the top_bar
         TextView textViewActivityTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewActivityTitle);
         textViewActivityTitle.setText(getResources().getString(stringTitleID).toString());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * This functions clears the app cache. The json responses are stored in che cacheDir or cacheExternalDir.
     * I clean them when the app is started. I only use the cache between the Fragments
     */

}
```

Is the fragments solution a good one? Why the fragment with the listview stays?
Should I use a ListFragment?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: My problem was in the XML. I was using <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment_place"..../> instead of <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/fragment_place"

Answer (score 0):

I think Tab Navigation is better but you can try this:

1) in your main activity add click listener to yours buttons first, then use a parameter to discriminate:

```
 button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
          changeFragment(1) 
        }
 };

public void changeFragment(int whichfragment){
    switch(whichfragment){
      case 1:
        fr=new FragmentOne();
        replaceFragment();
      break;
      case 2:
         fr=new FragmentTwo();
         replaceFragment();
      break;
    }

}
```

2) Now you can replace your fragment

```
 public void replaceFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
transaction.commit();
 }
```

Comment: Is it possibile to have custom buttons to switch tabs? Why do you think is better? I will test you code as soon as possible, thanks!

Comment: Yes you can create your own button. Maybe it helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074303/how-to-create-custom-shape-button-with-selector-in-android