# Round button without corners in Android

Tags: android, button, geometry

I am trying to create a simulated target with circle buttons of different sizes stacked on top of each other.  I have no issues in creating the circle buttons, the problem I have is that I want to make clicks the transparent corners on the top and bottom left and right pass through to the button below it.

Is there a better way of doing this?

[What the target looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMDlk.png)
[Target with circles drawn around problem areas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIeCc.png)

Comment: Check this answer on related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19583072/383414

Comment: What I have done previously for a similar type of thing - created a custom view, and drew the target, intercepted the `onTouch()`/`onClick()` events, and did calculations to see which ring the touches were in.