# Bounds in custom triangle button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-button, android-custom-drawable

I created a custom button as shown in the image.
My  problem is that the bounds still clickble.
Is there any way to wrap the triangle.

Image [custom button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCAoW.png)

My shape xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-10%"
        android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke  android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="30dp"/>
            <solid 
             android:color="@android:color/black" />

        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Button:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/triangle"
        android:id="@+id/button"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I also tried canvas approach and get the same problem.

Comment: Please post your code and XML file.

Comment: @HoangNguyen hi, I post my xml files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for my late reply. I don't know you have found the solution yet. 
Because `android:pivotX="-10%"` ,your black triangle have distance with the top edge.

You can remove `android:pivotX, android: pivotY`, and add `android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"`in your button like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
android:weightSum="1"
android:layout_marginBottom="-50dp"
>

<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/triangle"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now your black triangle has no distance with the top edge. But it doesn't really wrap the triangle. If you want to wrap the triangle, there are some solution (It's Not Easy):

> You can override the OnTouch Event method in a CustomView / CustomButton.
>
> Inside you have the MotionEvent were you can check if the Touch was inside your Triangle (with the help of some mathematics :P)

Or you can do the same:

[Android Custom Shape Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button)