# How to make custom shape (arrow on the sides pointing outwards) of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, material-components, material-components-android

I want to make my button look like the following. Can you please tell me, how to make a drawable xml file for the following?

like this image

[image]

Comment: better ad png in background

Comment: What have you done so far? Show us your code

Comment: try using 9 patch drawable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Custom Shape Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the standard `MaterialButton` in the [**Material Components Library**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) with the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.
Something like:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ButtomShapeArrow"
        ../>
```

with:

```
  <style name="ButtomShapeArrow">
    <item name="cornerFamily">cut</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
  </style>
```

### [image]

With **Jetpack Compose**:

```
Button(
    onClick = { /* do something */},
    shape = CutCornerShape(50)
){
    Text ("SHAPE")
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a drawable XML file inside your drawable

> background.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="27dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="628.0"
    android:viewportWidth="726.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
        android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
        android:strokeColor="#ffffff"
        android:strokeWidth="20" />
</vector>
```

Then in your layout file you can add the background like below

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#652ef0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World 2!" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This will give you output something like this 
[image: activity_main]

Answer (score 0):

If it were only the shape maybe a vector drawable would be enough, but to draw shape, icon and text, better to create your own Button class and draw things in the overriden onDraw. The shape can be drawn using a Path.