# Heart shaped button in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button

I have this application that I am working on and the user can mark some items as a favorite.
I want to use a heart shaped button for this functionality instead of the casual one is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Next question, please. (*Is it possible?* is not a specific question, and therefore isn't going to help you much. This site is for **specific questions**. You may want to spend some time reading [ask] for some suggestions about how to ask questions in a way that will improve your chances of getting help.)

Comment: question already answered : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use VectorAssets as below in XML.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M12,21.35l-1.45,-1.32C5.4,15.36 2,12.28 2,8.5 2,5.42 4.42,3 7.5,3c1.74,0 3.41,0.81 4.5,2.09C13.09,3.81 14.76,3 16.5,3 19.58,3 22,5.42 22,8.5c0,3.78 -3.4,6.86 -8.55,11.54L12,21.35z"/>
</vector>
```

You can create VectorAssets doing: **new Vector Asset > Change Icon** -- Here you can choose love vector asset. These VectorAssets, you can store in the drawable folder. Then you can import than in your XML layout file as

```
@drawable/<name_of_vectorAsset_xml>
```

For the demo, please see below picture. The VectorAsset XML file is **ic_favorite_black_24dp**
[image]

*You can change the color of the VectorAsset also. On click, you can replace VectorAsset with another Red colored VectorAsset to represent it favorite and so on.*

Comment: To be clear, you can choose File -> New -> Vector Asset
(it's not in any of the submenus, it's right inside the large 'New' menu)
Then you can click the icon next to "Clip Art" and change to a different clip art icon
You can search for "Fav" in the list of clip art to see a Heart
PS: I'd recommend changing the Opacity to near 100% so you can actually see it, otherwise it's a transparent (ghost) image

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a heart graphic asset and then putting it in an ImageButton, then for the animations you should work some more.

There is a Star/Rate button native, but nancy fancy.

I would recommend this for what you are looking for:
https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3038