# Custom shaped button in android

Tags: android, android-button, xml-layout

I want to create a custom shaped button like this:

[image]

**I'm able to achieve a similar thing by using a `RelativeLayout` and overlapping a rectangle and a circle.** But that way, I have to add 2 `onClickListaners`, one for each shape.

Is there a way in android ( other than using an image, because in image the entire rectangular view will be clickable and not just the button ) to create such a design using a single XML layout file ??

Comment: no, you cannot do that in xml only

Comment: @pskink then how is it possible ?

Comment: you need a custom `View` to: 1) draw your custom shape using `Canvas` API by overiding `View#onDraw` and 2) detect if click event is inside that shape inside a custom `View#onTouchEvent` method

Comment: @pskink Could you tell us why you think this is not possible in XML?

Comment: @KalaBalik how can you detect if `MotionEvent` is inside some complex shape? in xml...

Comment: @pskink I might be wrong but...can't we make this shape in an xml, set it as Button background, and just add a click event to the button? correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @mrid Just tried that, it didn't work. As expected, it worked as a rectangle and clicks worked even on the blank portion of the button (ImageButton).

Comment: Your approach can give you a lot of headaches. Instead create an ImageButton, and assign its android:src to a vector drawable that has the specific shape. Now, you can create that by hand or with a photoshop that exports the shape to either svg or png. Then you use same vector drawable to set up a mask.

Comment: @Fabio I've just checked the `Imagebutton` and I don't think he wants the working of an `Imagebutton`.

Comment: What I would've done instead of messing up with canvas is create a rectangular button and a circular imageview and set same `onClick` Method for them instead of creating two `onClickLister`s. Its an easy approach.

Comment: Also, drawables for them can be created in Photoshop and can be split as a rectangular and a circle.

Comment: @Fabio, suppose I have an oval image as a background to the button, will the click listener not work on the left-over area of the button ( rectangle button view - actual image shape ) ??

Comment: @mrid it will work in the blank area.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar that's what I want to avoid

Comment: Then as pskink said, use `Canvas` API by overriding `View.onDraw`

Comment: The mask will avoid taps on unwanted areas. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button

Answer (score 0):

you won't have to make two listener just make one listener for the RelativeLayout