# How to create custom buttons using a grid of masks?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I need to create a custom button layout and I cannot figure out how to make working buttons that don't overlap.

I've created an ImageView along with Buttons that have the masks as the background set to invisible, as to only display the ImageView.

ImageView:

[image: Just the ImageView]

Buttons and masks:

[image: W/Buttons (and their masks) visible]

It's not the most exact placement, but I'll take it.

Right now, I've only got each button using an onClick function and absolutely nothing happens.

Comment: For this I would make a subclass of constraintlayout and manually shape the buttons and position them relative to each other

Comment: That'd fix and help with positioning, but I don't see how that would help make working button masks.

Comment: Did you already check this question/answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13879492/9698068

Comment: @ReneEder Yep. The issue is, I don't know how to create the mask using shape negatives. The visible mask is just a png of what I want the clickable area to be that's set as the background.