# Android button design

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can i make a button in android as shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: Hi, please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861416/android-custom-shape-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Full credit to [fornewid/neumorphism](https://github.com/fornewid/neumorphism) :

Add `implementation 'com.github.fornewid:neumorphism:0.2.0'` to your Gradle

I've created a similar button

```
 <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="#191a1c"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorLight="#323639"
        app:neumorph_shadowElevation="6dp" />
```

**Preview :**

[image]